# When and where did "clam" come to mean a missed note in a musical performance?

Tags: etymology, terminology, slang, music

Someone just asked me in chat what a missed note in music is called. Without hesitation, I replied, "A clam." It's what I've always heard in academic and professional settings since forever.

Only now, having to explain its usage and origin, I went looking and found only informal origins and folk-etymology explanations. One such was the notion that it is derived from the expression "to clam up," meaning to fall silent (see Etymonline, [which attests it](https://www.etymonline.com/word/clam#etymonline_v_13756) as American from 1916 while noting that the word *clam* itself has been used as an interjection meaning ‘clam up’ since the 14th century). But there are problems with that. For one thing, a "clam" note is one that is played instead of the actually written or appropriate note. In other words, it *sounds* ... something that is the opposite of silence.

Here's [another attempt](https://www.mail-archive.com/horn@memphis.edu/msg03487.html) at explaining the origin:

> The origin of using the word "clam" to describe a missed note is rooted in
>   the theatre TTBOMK.  As I understand it, actors would describe an  untimely 
>   entrance or forgotten line as "making a clam."  Certainly, if  that was the 
>   case, horn players in the pit would have readily taken up the use  of the 
>   word and spread it around the musical community.

The "TTBOMK" gives it away as folk etymology, and the argument that follows is what I will charitably call less than rigorous.

Still, it does demonstrate that I'm not the only one who's ever heard the term. And really, almost everywhere I've ever played music the term has come up (though not about my playing—honest!). It's also not the only term used for a missed note (one I especially loved was "approximatura," which played nicely off the musical term *appogiatura*, but that's a story for another day).

And [The Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2008/03/clam/) says:

> The likening of a closed mouth, or the human mouth in general, to the bivalve sort of “clam” may underlie the use of “clam” to mean a missed or flubbed note, especially if the term originated in connection with wind instruments. This usage dates back to at least the early 1950s and since then has been applied to an error in any sort of musical or theatrical performance (“Bing Crosby … always said, ‘Leave the clams in, let ’em know I’m human,'” New York Times, 1991). Perhaps the “error” sense of the term lies in the failure of one’s “clam,” or mouth, to perform correctly.

... which is anything but definitive. Other possibilities listed in the piece are softened by statements like "it seems entirely logical that ..."

So can anybody provide an actual origin story for use of this term in this context?

Comment: What is TTMBOK?

Comment: @Mitch: "To the best of my knowledge?" (Note the missed note, which we shall henceforth call a clam by extension). And the mistake in ordering appears to be yours. ^_^

Comment: Ugh. Nevermind. I thought it was some reference to the particular theater.

Comment: Unsure. Is there any relation to the Latin *clam* (secretly or privately - not that a missed note is necessarily secret or private)?

Comment: Interesting question. I never knew a missed note was called a clam. My immediate thought was that it might be related to _clamour_ (in the sense of a disharmonic clangour), which an incorrect note can sometimes sound like. That’s just more random speculation, though.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin: Good question. I don't know the answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Also an interesting thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest coverage of *clam* in the sense of "mistake or misplayed musical note" that I've been able to find is in Harold Wentwoth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang*, first edition (1960):

> **clam** *n.* ... **5.** a mistake ; a boner 1952: "Radio men speak no worse English than the general average of American professional men, and ... on the average there are not really so horribly many out-and-out clams coming over the air." Letter in *N.Y. Her[ald] Trib[une]*, Apr. 3, 24/5.

J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994) cites the 1952 instance reported in Wentworth & Flexner as its first recorded occurrence of the usage, but then adds a slightly later occurrence, from 1955, and still later ones from 1964 and 1991:

> **clam** *n.* ... **5.** *Entertainment Industry.* a mistake, BONER; (*Jazz*) a misplayed note. **1952** in *DAS*. **1955** *Down Beat* (Nov. 30) 47: I'd say that was a band that doesn't work together regularly ... because there were a few clams in the ensemble. **1964** *New Yorker* (Apr. 25) 195: Clams proliferate. **1991** *N.Y. Times* (Dec. 1) H 33: Bing Crosby ... always said, 'Leave the clams in, let 'em know I'm human.'"

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995) reports that the expression  goes back to the 1940s but does not cite any historical examples:

> **clam** ... **4** ***n*** *1940s jazz musicians* A wrong or sour note; =CLINKER

Coincidentally (or not), Chapman & Kipfer also notes that *clambake* had a special meaning in jazz circles, starting in the 1930s:

> **clambake** ... **2** ***n*** *1930s jazz musicians* =JAM SESSION

So if *clam* originated as a jazz term in the 1940s, rather than more broadly as an U.S. entertainment industry term by the early 1950s, a *clam* (wrong note) may have referred to the sort of mistake that a jazz musician would expect to encounter more frequently at a *clambake* (jam session) than at a formal, paying performance.

Clarence Major, *Juba to Jive: A Dictionary of African-American Slang* (1994) lends some support to this theory in its entries for *clam* and *clambake*, both of which cite entries that originated in Robert Gold, *A Jazz Lexicon* (1964):

> **Clam** *n.* (1940s–1950s) in jazz, a misplaced note. ([*Jazz Lexicon*], p. 59) Example: "The band isn't in good shape tonight. Too many clams." ...
>
> **Clambake** *n.* (1930s–1950s) an "ad lib {jam} session ... not in the groove"; a "swing" or jam session; (1950s) a jazz or rhythm-and-blues musical affair that doesn't come off well. ([*Jazz Lexicon*], p. 58)  ...

And H. Brook Webb, "[The Slang of Jazz](https://books.google.com/books?id=tsQ4AAAAMAAJ&q=%22clambake+same+as+jam+session%22&dq=%22clambake+same+as+jam+session%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin0qDet9jhAhXtN30KHYcGC1gQ6AEIKjAA)," in *American Speech* (1937) confirms that *clambake* was used to refer to a jam session in the 1930s [combined snippets]:

> **CLAMBAKE.** Same as *jam session*.
>
> ...
>
> **JAM SESSION.** An after hour's gathering of musicians of the hot persuasion from different bands, for relaxation, refreshment, and to jam a few numbers with everyone cutting a lick or two when the spirit moves.

---

I'm not entirely sold on the *clam*-by-way-of-*clambake* explanation, in part because it doesn't persuasively indicate why a word chosen presumably for its pleasant associations with relaxed good times (*clambake*) should have yielded a derogatory term for faulty musicianship (*clam*), and in part because it isn't clear to me that *clam* originated as jazz talk rather than in the wider world of U.S. entertainment.

Nevertheless, I think that 1930–1952 is very likely the approximate origin period for both *clambake* and *clam* in the relevant senses. And any better explanation of the origin of *clam* as "mistake" should devote at least a little time to explaining why the jazz terms *clam* and *clambake* are **not** related.

---

**Update (May 21, 2021):**

After posting this answer, I bought a copy of Robert Gold, A Jazz Lexicon (1964), which (as noted in my original answer) Clarence Major cites in his entries for *clam* and *clambake*. Gold's entries for the two terms are quite a bit more detailed than Majors's and are worthy of reproduction at full length:

> **clam** n. {poss. partly from being alliterative with its older synonym *clinker* [which Gold views as "onomatopoeic"]; more prob. shortened form of the derogatory sense of clambake; current since c. 1950; see also GOOF} A misplayed note; also, for a rare verb use, see 1961 quot. — **1955** *Down Beat*, 30 Nov., p. 47. I'd say that was a band that doesn't work together regularly ... because there were a few clams in the ensemble. — **1961** *Down Beat*, 2 Feb., p. 30. Hubbard sounds positively uncomfortable and clams in royal style at the beginning.
>
> **clambake**, *n.* {by analogy with the standard sense; current c. 1930–c. 1938 in an approbative or a neutral sense, but increasingly since c. 1938 in a pejorative sense} See 1952 and first 1955 quots. — **1937** *American Speech*, Feb., p. 46. *clambake*: same as *jam session*. — **1938** *Cab Callaway: Hi De Ho*, p. 16. *clambake*: ad lib session, every man for himself, a jam session not in the groove. — **1949** *Music Library Association Notes*, Dec., p. 41. clambake: gathering of hot musicians. Also used in a derogatory sense to mean an affair that does not come off well. — **1952** *A History of Jazz in America*, p. 350. clambake: earlier used synonymously (and honorifically) with "jam session," later descriptive of an improvised or arranged session which doesn't come off. — **1955** *The Encyclopedia of Jazz*, p. 346, clambake: Originally, a jam session; currently, an unsuccessful, disorganized session. — **1955** *Hear Me Talkin to Ya*, p. 265. Everybody got kind of half-high and it ended up in a clambake.

Gold's discussion and cited quotations make a strong circumstantial case for *clam* to have emerged from the pejorative sense of *clambake*—a sense that I was not aware of when I wrote my original answer. The timing is certainly right for such an origin, since *clambake* had evidently acquired negative connotations at least as early as Cab Calloway's *Hi De Ho* glossary, which was published in 1938, and the paper trail for *clam* in the relevant sense begins about a dozen years later.

Comment: Very nicely researched, crafted, and argued. I'll hold off on the checkmark for a little while on the minuscule chance that someone comes up with a better, more exhaustive treatment. But I wouldn't want to hang from a rope until that happens.

Comment: I've also heard "clambake" used to mean a performance with a lot of clams (wrong notes). I don't know how widespread that usage is, but the word may have developed two parallel meanings in music slang, especially if one meaning was mostly confined to jazz.

Answer (score 0):

Term also figures prominently in Buddy Rich's famed bus oration, attacking his band for missed notes.  (Available in part on youtube with added illustrations!)

Comment: What evidence do you have that this was the origin of the term?

Comment: A date would also be useful.